# Encapsulating TCP packets

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, encapsulation, wifi

I am working on a research paper about 802.11 wireless networks. One of the subjects that I am researching is encapsulating whole TCP packets in UDP segments. Specifically, I am looking at encapsulating the TCP packets sent between a wireless client and an access point.

The reason for this is to stop the interaction between TCP and 802.11 MAC.

My question is this: Is it technically feasible to introduce UDP encapsulation between two points without the use of a proxy or server based translator? If so, what sort of things would need to be done?

I am not a programmer so I do not need detailed answers, just a high level overview.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's feasible to do TCP-within-UDP encapsulation. There's an IETF draft on the subject: [UDP-Encapsulated Transport Protocols](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-denis-udp-transport-00). Note that the author's affiliation is with Nokia, so they're looking at exactly the same kind of thing you are.

With any encapsulation protocol, however, there has to be code in *some* protocol stack on each end of the connection. So if you don't use a proxy, you'd need native support in both the client and the access point. As an analogy, look at the architecture of [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec), which uses IP-within-IP encapsulation and has essentially the same properties about locus of implementation required.